# Got an error: Undefined subroutine &Scalar::Util::looks_like_number called

Tags: perl, movabletype

I have a site using Movable Type, and when trying to upload a picture to a post, the error showed up, and now the admin area only shows blank pages with that error message.

I read on a blog post in Japanese (via Google translate) and it mentions the mt-wizard.cgi, but I couldn't understand how to fix it.

Is is something that needs to be installed in the server? Any ideas of where I could possibly start?

Comment: Can you give more details about the server (specifically, the Perl) environment? It sounds like you might be missing Scalar/Util.pm, which I think is part of default Perl, but I am not sure what versions that is true for.

Comment: The site is on a shared hosting (with cpanel). The site was working fine, and we certainly haven't changed anything.

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz `Scalar::Util` is in the core in Perl 5.8.8 and I don't think things get taken out of the core once they are in.

Comment: What version of Movable Type are you using? I found `Scalar::Util` has been part of Perl since 5.7.3, btw.

Comment: The part of MT I am guessing is causing that error was added in MT 5.2.4, but I do not see how the error is happening.

Comment: I'm using MT 5.2.10 (open source version). I just ran the mt-check.cgi script (I forgot about it), and it's all good. It even says that Scalar::Util is installed, but it's "Version unknown". I will contact my host, because I suspect he did something. The site was working fine earlier today.

Comment: @chilemagic sometimes they do (after a good period of warning), but that one certainly asn't been :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `looks_like_number` subroutine needs to be included in your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

if ( Scalar::Util::looks_like_number("a") ) {
  print "Look like a number!\n";
} else {
  print "No\n";
}
```

When the `use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);` is commented out, you'll get that error.

```
Undefined subroutine &Scalar::Util::looks_like_number called at main.pl line 4.
```

Find the file that is giving you the error and add the `use` statement to it to include that subroutine and it should get you past that error at least.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find a spot were it did something, but now I get a different error: Got an error: List::Util object version 1.21 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.34 I think my host must have done some update to Perl, and that's why this is happening. Do you agree?

Comment: @coopersita yes, that error means that the pure-perl part of your perl install doesn't match the architecture-specific part, which means someone did something funny.

Comment: Thanks, again. I've emailed my host.